# Wordpress list custom taxonomy terms from search results

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a custom post type called 'projects' with custom taxonomies. I have created multiple projects and tagged these projects with the custom taxonomy called 'company'.

What I'm looking to do is when I search for a project that is tagged in multiple 'companies' is to have a section called 'companies' on the search results page that lists just the companies.

What I have at the minute is when I search and multiple projects are displayed it duplicates the 'company' taxonomy' but I only want to show one taxonomy and remove any duplicates.

the code I have now is:

```
<?php                   
  // the query
  $search_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

  <?php if ( $search_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <ul class="search-result">

      <!-- pagination here -->

        <!-- the loop -->
        <?php while ( $search_query->have_posts() ) : $search_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
          <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->postname, 'companies', 'Disipline: ', ', ' ); ?>
        </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <!-- end of the loop -->

        <!-- pagination here -->

    </ul>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>
      <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

If I have search results of 2 projects I'm getting 2 lots of term list ie film,video,film... But i just want it to say film,video

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my issue so posting my answer.

```
<div class="search-container">
  <h2 class="pagetitle">In: <span>Discipline</span></h2>
    <ul class="search-result">
      <?php
        $_terms = get_terms( array('sectors') );
        foreach ($_terms as $term) :
        $term_slug = $term->slug;
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
        $_posts = new WP_Query( array(
          'post_type'         => 'projects',
          's'                 => $s,
          'posts_per_page'    => 10, //important for a PHP memory limit warning
          'tax_query' => array(
            array(
              'taxonomy' => 'sectors',
              'field'    => 'slug',
              'terms'    => $term_slug,
            ),
        ),
    ));
    if( $_posts->have_posts() ) :
      echo '<li>'. '<h3>' . $term->name . '</h3>';
      echo '<p>' . $term->description . '</p>';
      // We successfully got a link. Print it out.
      echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . 'view page' .         '</a></li>';
    ?>

    <?php
      endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        endforeach;
    ?>
   </ul>
</div>
```